# structure layout differences in mozilla and chrome

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, vendor-prefix

I have this simple website that works well on ie and chrome, but it's a little funky in firefox. I have a div which is a yellow rectangle and a nav bar the same color that sits on top of it, but for some reason, firefox moves the nav right underneath the div. Here is the code i have:

```
<section>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav id="flexbox">
    <div><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></div>
    <div><a href="events.html">Events</a></div>
    <div><a href="default.html">Home</a></div>
    <div><a href="membership.html">Membership</a></div>
    <div><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></div>
</nav>
</div>
</section>
```

with the following css:

```
section {
    max-width:100%;
    margin:-2px;
    padding:-2px;
    border:-2px;
}

#wrapper {
    max-height:40px;
    width:90%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#f5b00e;
}

#flexbox {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:-webkit-box-flex;
    width:65%;
    min-width:600px;
    max-height:40px;
    -ms-flex-pack:distribute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#f5b00e;

    -webkit-box-flex:1.0;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;

    -moz-box-flex:1.0;
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-align:center;
 }

#flexbox > div {
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 80px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align:right;

    -webkit-box-flex:1.0;
    display:-webkit-box;

    -moz-box-flex:1.0;
    display:-moz-box;
}
```

Comment: Why are you limiting the height of "wrapper", then pushing "flexbox" outside of it with margin-top?

Comment: @Diodeus - thanks, that was a silly mistake. I'm surprised it was working in chrome and ie. Do you know why?

Comment: @Diodeus - and do you know why mozilla is also the only one that doesn't center the flexbox horizontally? margin:auto; is not working either.

Comment: try: margin: 0 auto; display: block;  (for your last question about centring)

Comment: @matt - thanks, but if i do that it messes it up on the other browsers, and still doesn't look quite right in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create some CSS rules for firefox only you can add the following to your style sheet and put the firefox only styles within it, see example below:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .body a {
     color:red;
  }
}
```

Generally you should only use this as a last resort if firefox is refusing to do as you ask, such as it does not allow background positions so I use it in that case to load a different background image sized for just firefox users.

Comment: thanks for the tip. It definitely made a difference, but it still doesn't quite center the flexbox inside the div, it's still hanging noticeably closer to the left. Any ideas?